# Custom headers not passed to backend service while using AWS ALB with Custom Domain name

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a spring boot component which exposes a Rest API. This component is exposed using an AWS ALB with a custom domain name configured.
I have now added some headers necessary for my Rest API. There's OpenAPI configured in my app which similar to swagger can help my send request to the Rest API.

The problem I see is that the headers are not passed to the my Rest application behind the ALB.

**When executing the API request on Local machine, the headers are available to the Rest app. But when requested over the ALB exposed endpoint, headers are lost.**

Is there any configuration to be done on the ALB the make sure headers are always forwarded?

Comment: It might be that your custom header is not a valid header and being dropped by ALB. See similar questions: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094640/adding-a-custom-request-header-to-aws-alb-through-lambda-functions) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848623/what-does-alb-consider-a-valid-header-field) [Q3](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/n16w1h/application_loadbalancer_custom_headers/)